# Login with Facebook API for Instagram

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

I am using social media import feature in my website. Customer comes to my website and login with facebook or instagram and their media details are being fethced into my system. I have created separate app for both social media solutions.

I want to integrate Login with Facebook for Instagram media then is there any possible solution for the same? What would be the process?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, Can someone update on this to me?

Comment: Would someone update me on this?

Comment: Is there something can help me out?